# Setting ad width to match_parent

Tags: java, android, xml, ads

So I have ads in my app and i wan't their width to be `match_parent`. If I set it to `match_parent` it still displays as `wrap_content`, and if I set it in java file like this `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);` i get a crash with this message:  `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ad size can only be set once on AdView`

Here's the xml and java of my ads:

```
 AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);



   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

If i set it to SMART_BANNER i get that error I mentioned above, even though I delete   `ads:adSize="BANNER"` line from xml code.

Answer (score 1):

you can use FULL_WIDTH

```
ads:adSize="FULL_WIDTHx50"
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub_id"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

But keep in mind that if advertiser has provided all correct resources than and then only your ad will be visible in width of match_patent

Comment: But why's then on all the other apps ad width takes whole screen area on width?

Comment: I have added one attribute which is smart_banner may be that's why Google find most suitable ad for that.

Comment: If this answer help you to solve your problem then please accept it as answer.